# How can a django model field relate to multiple model?

Tags: python, django, model, meta

suppose I have three model like this:

```
 class video(models.Model):
       name=models.CharField(max_length = 100)

 class image(models.Model):
       name=models.CharField(max_length = 100)

 class comments(models.Model):
       content=models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

now i want to notic the user if their video or image get an comment

this is what i want

the message model:

```
class message(models.Model):
       type=models.CharField(max_length = 100) # 'video' or 'image'
       video_or_image=models.ForeignKey(video or image)

       #the type is just a string to tell if the comment is about the video or image
       #video_or_image need to be video foreignkey or image foreignkey depends on type
```

is it possible.

I currently work around this by two method

**first**：

```
   class message(models.Model):
       type = models.CharField(max_length = 100) # 'video' or 'image'
       video_or_image_id = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
       #
```

**second**

```
  class message(models.Model):
       type=models.CharField(max_length = 100) # 'video' or 'image'
       video=models.ForeignKey(video)
       image=models.ForeignKey(image)
       # if the comment is about video just leave the image empty
```

if the one field to multiple model can not be done, then which my work around method is better, or help me with a better one!

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey).

This is also the way [contrib.comments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/external-packages/#comments) relates [comments to commented](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) items.